# Executing TestNG test cases from a CSV file

Tags: testng

I have a bunch of test cases in TestNG. At present I have used @groups to execute test cases based on environment. What I am trying to achieve is , I will be putting down all the test case name and group in a CSV file. For eg -

TestCaseName Group Test_Case1 Smoke,Sanity Test_Case2 Regression

So before executing a test, user will provide input parameter as Smoke and only the Smoke test will get executed.

I tried 'annotation transformer' but it can restricts only at method level. When I tried for class, it was throwing Null Pointer Exception.

Another issue is my test class contains both test method as well as some other non test methods which calls reusable methods. As a result I can't provide @Test in class level.

I want a way to read my class name (Simple Class Name) from CSV along with group and based on that the test class should be enabled / disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize TestNG configuration file and [grouping](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) feature of TestNG. With your test you should add appropriate groups. For example:

```
@Test(groups={"Smoke","Sanity"}
public void Test_Case1(){
}

@Test(groups={"Regression"}
public void Test_Case2(){
}
```

To execute specific groups trough config file:

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="Smoke"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
    ...
</test>
```

To execute specific groups through command line you can use

```
-groups <comma-separated list of groups>
```

With maven or ANT  can pass `groups` parameter at the time of execution using

```
-Dgroups=<comma-separated list of groups>
```

If you use [QAF - TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) it provides way to define [meta-data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario-meta-data.html) that can be used in [meta-data filter](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario_metadatata_filter_include_exclude_prop.html) in addition to groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I have been doing that already. What I am struggling now is I am trying to store the test case name and group name in a csv file. One class will contain only 1 test method. So when I execute it from maven it will retrieve & execute only those test cases from the csv file belonging to that group

Comment: You can implement method selector as well for that purpose.